# Change style in class

Tags: css, class, styles

I want to change style in css in element with class="paginate_button active".
But .paginate_button.active and paginate_button active doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: show us some code

Comment: <li class="paginate_button active">

Comment: Please edit your post above, and also we need the code of the css classes

Comment: I said that i tried use .paginate_button.active and .paginate_button active in my css file and it doesn't work space is little problem.

Answer (score 1):

**The question seemed a bit vague, so I'll post how to access the CSS of elements using CSS and using Javascript.**

---

**CSS**

To access an element with both the classes `paginate_button` and `active`, you can use the following:

`.paginate_button .active {
    /* Styles go here */
}`

The `.` selector in CSS is used to identify classes.

---

**Javascript**

You can access HTML elements in Javascript using the following method:

`document.getElementsByClassName(query)`

So, if I wanted to get a list of all elements with the "paginate_button" class, I could do:

`var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("paginate_button");`

Then I could iterate through the list with a loop if there was more than one element. Or simply, if there is only one element with that class name, you could access the first element in the array `elements`:

`var element = document.getElementsByClassName("paginate_button")[0];`

Please note this may throw an error if there are no elements with the class "paginate_button".

You can then modify the CSS of that element by access it with:

`element.style`

This returns a CSSStyleDeclaration which allows you to directly edit the CSS of that element.

You can see a list of properties of CSSStyleDeclaration [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference), which are similar to the respective CSS styles.